# Excel and C#, Very Large Data Sets, and Memory Leaks

Tags: c#, excel, memory

I'm working on a decently large data set in Excel format -- about 741,798 hours of data, with information collected for each minute of each hour. I've been asked to help out in processing this data set and deriving some very basic metrics from it.

I decided to work in C#/.NET because that's what I'm most familiar with in terms of accessing Excel, but I've run into two issues:

1. I've noticed the memory usage on my PC climbing slowly in between times that I debug the code. This set off some pretty loud warning bells in my mind and surprised me given that I thought I had done a decent job with explicit garbage collection.
2. Excel, unlike in previous attempts, is not playing along and handing me values from the spreadsheet for some reasons.

Attached below are parts of my code.

Here's the algorithm that reads in intensity data (this is data collected from individuals whose exercise intensity was measured over long periods of time, hence the name):

```
public static void ReadMinuteIntensities(string directory, Manager m, bool clearSubjects = true)
        {
            ExcelHandle excelHandle = new ExcelHandle(directory + "\\minuteIntensitiesWide_merged.xlsx");

            bool garbageCollected = false;

            try // Try to read in our data.
            {
                string currentSubjectId = excelHandle.GetCell(1, 0); // In the 1st row, 0th column, there will be our first subject id.
                Subject currentSubject = null;
                string currentDate = excelHandle.GetCell(1, 1);
                string currentHour = excelHandle.GetCell(1, 1); // The 1st column, 1st row, we find our first day/hour information.
                                                        // int column = 2; // Start in the column that gives the first minute data.
                int row = 1; // Start in the row that gives data for the first hour.

                // If we were told to clear the subjects from the list, do so.
                if (clearSubjects)
                    m.ClearSubjects();

                // Add our first subject as preparation.
                m.AddSubject(currentSubjectId);

                // While we have not reached a line where there is no subject ID (i.e. where there is no more data, continue reading in data).
                while (excelHandle.GetCell(row, 0) != "")
                {
                    // If we've detected that data is being described for a new subject, add a new subject to the list and reset our current subject ID.
                    if (excelHandle.GetCell(row, 0) != currentSubjectId)
                    {
                        m.AddSubject(excelHandle.GetCell(row, 0));
                        currentSubjectId = excelHandle.GetCell(row, 0);
                        currentSubject = m.GetLastSubject();
                    }

                    // Add a new date/time data object to the current subject.
                    currentSubject.AddDateTimeData(DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(excelHandle.GetCell(row, 1))));

                    // Collect data for each minute in that date/hour slot.
                    for (int minute = 0; minute < 60; minute++)
                    {
                        // Get the appropriate minute for the current date/time and set the intensity according to what's given in the spreadsheet.
                        currentSubject.GetDateTimeData(DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(excelHandle.GetCell(row, 1))))
                            .GetMinute(minute)
                            .SetIntensity(Convert.ToInt32(excelHandle.GetCell(row, minute + 2)));
                    }

                    row++; // Move down one row to collect new data.
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) // If for some reason it doesn't work, catch the exception by cleaning up any memory still in use, releasing objects, and closing everything to do with Excel.
            {

                Console.WriteLine("*********************************************************************************************************");
                // Console.WriteLine(e.);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine(e.TargetSite);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("*********************************************************************************************************");

                excelHandle.Close();

                garbageCollected = true;
            }

            // Do all that same garbage collection here just in case something bad happens.
            if (!garbageCollected)
            {
                excelHandle.Close();
            }
        }
```

And here's the code for my class that interfaces with Excel:

```
public class ExcelHandle
    {
        string path; // The path to the files we're looking for.
        Application excel; // The Excel application itself.
        Workbook workbook;
        Worksheet worksheet;

        public ExcelHandle(string Path)
        {
            path = Path;
            excel = new _Excel.Application();
            workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(path); // Open the workbook at the given directory.

            Console.WriteLine(workbook.Name);
            
            foreach (Worksheet ws in workbook.Worksheets)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ws.Name);
            }

            worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1]; // Get the first worksheet.
        }

        public string GetCell(int row, int column)
        {
            // Excel has no (0, 0) defined locally; it starts at (1, 1). Therefore, because I want to use an origin of (0, 0), I need to modify the indeces.
            return worksheet.Cells[row + 1, column + 1].Value2;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This does all the necessary garbage collecting etc.
        /// </summary>
        public void Close()
        {
            // Force garbage collection so we don't get screwed by memory leaks.
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            // Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);

            // Close the workbook.
            workbook.Close();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);

            // Close the application.
            excel.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
        }
    }
```

Any advice regarding eliminating memory leaks and/or ideas about what I'm doing wrong accessing the Excel file?

Thanks.

Comment: why aren't you using a database?

Comment: I would get data from Excel using oledb instead of using the Interop.  The Interop is very slow and inificient and may account for your memory issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, as you stated, you have run into “two” issues that do not appear to be related. Please [edit] you question to focus on only “one” issue. I would assume the second issue, is more important than the first memory issue. In reference to the second issue, in my tests, the code is returning the correct values from the worksheet. When you describe the problem as… _”… not playing along and handing me values from the spreadsheet for some reasons.”_ … does not really help. Is there an error? Wrong values returned? No values returned? What specifically is not working as expected?

Comment: Also, I will assume that the problem you may be having is that the cell values from the worksheet are retuned, however, they are the wrong values. I can only guess that you may be having a small indexing logic issue based upon the comment in the code. Specifically, the first comment in the `GetCell` method. There is… _”Excel has no (0, 0) defined locally; it starts at (1, 1), …”_ .…This is true; however, this is not true if the worksheet has a header row. If the sheet has a header row, as it appears it does, then the actual start of the data would be at row 2 column 1 (2, 1), not (1, 1).

Comment: As far as the first memory issue is concerned, more context is needed. As commented already, there are other third-party Excel libraries that are better and faster than interop. However, I am also aware that this may not be an option. In that case, extra care should be taken when dealing with the MS COM objects. Example, the whole `ExcelHandle` class looks questionable to me. It is odd to “open” the Excel file, then exit… Leaving the calling code to perform the `ExcelHandle`’s `Close` method. This forces the calling code to close the file. This looks like a problem waiting to be discovered.

Comment: One approach is to open the Excel file, get the data and store the data into some collection. This guarantees the proper releasing of the resources and allows the calling code to forget about closing the Excel file. I am also aware that this may be a problem if the worksheet is large. However, this leads to another question… How many “different” `ExcelHandle` objects are created when the code executes? If there are many “different” `ExcelHandle` objects created, it is not difficult to see a memory problem brewing. You need to provide a better description of how all this is put together.

Comment: When we had large amounts of data to play with, we used SAS to slice it into csv files for excel.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies; these are very helpful. I'll look into a 3rd-party tool to manage Excel. @JohnG, you correctly identified my vaguely-worded issue and I think you are correct. I think I see what may be the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use get_Value() method to read the cells of the sheet instead of accessing each cell using the Cells[i,j].Value2. the two dot access is not letting the objects to be released.